# Excel workbook not responding

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2010 and am having difficulty with one old workbook created in Excel 2003. Lots of symptoms to report!

No other workbooks are giving me this problem. This problem file usually causes "MS Excel - (workbook name.xls) [Compatibility Mode] (Not responding) and a blank screen apart from the task bar and this Excel message on a single line across the top of the screen. Waiting doesn't solve the problem. If I close Excel and choose the "Close program" option, it sometimes shows me the file as I remember it for a couple of seconds, then the program closes. Re-opening the file just gives the same behaviour again. During the first few seconds of loading, I can see the message "Contacting server for information" at the bottom of the Excel screen.

In Task Manager I can find EXCEL.EXE *32 running. I'm using Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.

This is a file I use regularly in projects as a specialised calculator, and so I re-copy it each time and save it to save the calculation records in the project file. I've found that versions of the workbook created even several years ago and have given no trouble until now all suffer this problem, so it looks like a problem with Excel 2010. This is the first time I've tried to open these files since migrating from a Win XP computer running Excel 2003.

Please can anyone help me to open the file and to resolve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There might be a calculation or a marcro activated on start up that messes things up.

Try the following:

Open the Excel application, with a blank workbook. Set calculation to manual. Now look up your Macro settings and set these to "disable with notifications".

With these things set, open your misbehaving workbook again and see what happens now. Dont let the macros (if any) start yet! Open the VBA Editor window and check for a script in Workbook called Workbook_Open. If that is present check its content or put a break in and debug it.

Let us know what you find, if any.

**UPDATE:** 
It sounds like there is a database link to an external source that is trying to refresh on startup but isnt working correctly (anymore). I now remember likewise behaviour when I had an Excel workbook with tons of SQL queries in it that (in case of showing a complete table or view by applying `SELECT * FROM ...`) could overlap other data and that would create autoshutdowns for me. Change the option in the Trust Center for External Content to Disable when you open this workbook and let us know!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've done as you suggested, but the problem remains. I opened a couple of workbooks just to ensure that the macros were still disabled and calculation was still in manual. On opening the problem workbook, again I saw the "Contacting the server" message at the bottom, then the screen went blank apart from the task bar and top line saying ""MS Excel - (workbook name.xls) [Compatibility Mode] (Not responding). However after maybe 30 seconds this time it did open, but it kept "not responding" from time to time. In macros, I find something very odd. Running out of characters..

Comment: There are 9 macros listed allegedly from a workbook that I did open this morning trying to see what was wrong. I remember these macros, they are all ones that I wrote and worked in the past. No macros from the current (problem) workbook are shown, although I suspect it has none of its own, and none from personal.xls where there are maybe a dozen normally (is this because macros are "off"?) Normally I'd be able to unhide personal.xls, but I can't find it, unhide is greyed out.I tried saving it as an xlsm, and this file opened immediately for a few seconds, then went "not responding again".

Comment: (During the above, that workbook was NOT open, so how Excel was reporting its macros I don't know.) The problem one, saved as xlsm, is not working again. There are no macros listed at all now! I'm off for a reboot.

Comment: Maybe there are database links in it? Could you change the setting for that and try again? It sounds like there is a database link to an external source that is trying to refresh on startup but isnt working correctly (anymore)

Comment: Rebooted and trying to get it to open again. The xls one wouldn't, but the xlsm one did without that message for some reason. I'm now looking at connections, and there are none. Curiously, personal xlsm is shown in the document recovery list together with several versions of the problem file. So I've re-opened the xls problem version, got not responding again. I left it for 10-15 minutes and it came back. There are no connections listed. I've now got all my Personal.xlsm macros listed, there are none in this workbook. They are still off and calc is manual. Trying to save it - NR again :-(

Answer (score 1):

I have a client with the same issue. The problem was resolved by removing all the logo's (Images) from the sheet. It appears that the logo contains a link to some web site. I copied the logo into paint and copied it back.

Problem Solved!

It appears that an object placed in the sheet can have its own links embedded in it???

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Keith, I've not opened the workbook since the original question, so I still have the problem. It did have a number of my own logos in it, but deleting them all has not resolved the problem. I think you're on the right track though - there's an external link somewhere that I can't find.

Comment: Having deleted the logos and saved the file as xlsm when it eventually started to respond, I now find it is working again. I've re-instated one logo (which gives no trouble when pasted into Word etc) and it's still OK. Quit while you're winning! I'm considering the problem solved now. I've put auto cal back on and macros back on, still OK. Many thanks to all who helped.